# Import CSV data from a txt file skipping the first line and adding headers

Tags: excel, vba

I was provided with a *.txt* file that represents a set data delimited with a semicolon. The first line consists of 5 data fields, independent from the rest of the lines. Meanwhile, the other lines represent a data set delimited in 16 fields (no header line is included).
The issue is that I'm having trouble to write the code to do the following in excel:

- Insert the first line in the range A1:E1
- Create a ListObject Table from the rest of the data in the A3 cell, while adding their corresponding headers.

I've run out of ideas and I don't know how to approach the issue. Many thanks!

Ps. the data consists of arround 20.000+ entries so I don't know if iterating through the delimiters is efficient.

I've tried to modify the original input file, but I've run into some issue removing the first line and adding the headers while conserving the data of the errased line in the workbook. Furthermore, it seems that I cannot add a List object table unless the data is imported from a csv file, which implies a file conversion.

**SAMPLE CSV**

```txt
COUNTRY;31/12/2024;31/12/2024;1;NA002
EUR;1;XXXX;;ZZZZ;YY;;-99374;;;-84750;DEP;;-20474
EUR;1;XXXX;;ZZZZ;YY;;-72843;;;-55582;DEP;;-25107
EUR;1;XXXX;;ZZZZ;YY;;-43929;;;-58231;DEP;;-19313
EUR;1;XXXX;;ZZZZ;YY;;-63419;;;-23753;DEP;;-58099
EUR;1;XXXX;;ZZZZ;YY;;-15823;;;-10315;DEP;;-29964
EUR;1;XXXX;;ZZZZ;YY;;-25517;;;-51326;DEP;;-9411
EUR;1;XXXX;;ZZZZ;YY;;-72852;;;-46947;DEP;;-46277
EUR;1;XXXX;;ZZZZ;YY;;-62011;;;-58741;DEP;;-67422
EUR;1;XXXX;;ZZZZ;YY;;-11243;;;-85323;DEP;;-85026
EUR;1;XXXX;;ZZZZ;YY;;-54993;;;-34625;DEP;;-20409
EUR;1;XXXX;;ZZZZ;YY;;-17647;;;-58004;DEP;;-49106
EUR;1;XXXX;;ZZZZ;YY;;-78266;;;-31639;DEP;;-37452
EUR;1;XXXX;;ZZZZ;YY;;-95180;;;-32508;DEP;;-79336
EUR;1;XXXX;;ZZZZ;YY;;-50861;;;-33265;DEP;;-33790
EUR;1;XXXX;;ZZZZ;YY;;-8484;;;-98502;DEP;;-99399
EUR;1;XXXX;;ZZZZ;YY;;-55098;;;-52802;DEP;;-4358
EUR;1;XXXX;;ZZZZ;YY;;-81368;;;-86121;DEP;;-86581
```

Comment: Record a macro while opening the file in Excel using `Data Tab >> Get Data >> From File >> From Text/CSV`   That will load the data into a worksheet, from there you can copy /paste it to where it needs to go.

Comment: @Tim Williams Thanks for the quick reply! I have tried that, but it would mean I would have to exclude the first row from the Query and then add headers, then access the file again to extract the first line, is this the best way to approach the import of the data?

Comment: You can't import the complete file to a worksheet in one step?

Comment: Use Power Query to do it. PQ is intended to do it in the best way.

Comment: @IBas you don't need to exclude the first row, you can just import the whole thing, then insert a row for the headers, with VBA. The macro recorder should work fine for that too.

Comment: @Tim Williams, yes but it inserts the first line as a part of the Table, which I would like to exclude. I cannot insert the data as values of a range and then create the Table if thats what you mean.

Comment: Please provide a sample CSV document we can work with **as text which can be copy/pasted**. It's not that difficult, but will be easiest in Power Query or VBA.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I've just included a sample of how the csv document would be structured

Comment: Finally, I would to point out that I was under the impression that it would be optimal to exclude the first line and appending the headers prior to the import of the data as a ListObject Table. Otherwise, it would be sensible to first import it by Power Query and then filter out undesired data and adding headers as pointed out firstly by @TimWilliams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a Power Query version:

I set up three queries

- Read in the entire table in a single column
- Process just the first line
- Process the other lines.

Queries get pasted into the Advanced Editor in Power Query (`Get & Transform`) as new queries from `blank`

For the first query, there are many ways to select the file. However, I just hard-coded it:

Also, rename this Query something like `Read CSV`

```
//Read in the CSV file as a single column
//Buffering might improve performance

// then this will be fed to the two queries that return the first line and the other lines

let
    Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents("C:\Users\ron\Desktop\New csv.csv"),[Columns=1, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None])
in 
     Table.Buffer(Source)
```

The result looks like:
[image]

When you go to save this query, select `Close and Load to` and when the next dialog opens select `Connection Only`

Then the `First Row` query:

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRecords({Table.First(#"Read CSV")}),
    Split = Table.SplitColumn(Source,"Column1",Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(";",QuoteStyle.Csv)),

//Set the data types
    #"Type Data" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Split, 
        List.Zip({Table.ColumnNames(Split), {type text, type date,type date, Int64.Type, type text }}),"en-GB")
in
    #"Type Data"
```

`Close and Load` will send the Query to a new worksheet.
You may want to rename the column headers.

Then for the other rows, another simple query:

```
let
    Source = Table.RemoveFirstN(#"Read CSV",1),
    Split = Table.SplitColumn(Source,"Column1", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(";", QuoteStyle.Csv))
in
    Split
```

`Close and Load to` and instead of New worksheet select `Existing Worksheet` and select the first cell.

- Adding column names and setting the data type for this query is simple, and can be done from the user interface.

Results of the above on the Excel Worksheet:

[image]

Comment: It seems that it only imports 8 columns for me, is there any reason why this could happen?

Comment: @IBas What exactly do you mean? The first query does the importing. And everything should be in one column as shown in the first screenshot. Please be more specific.

Comment: [link](https://imgur.com/a/OabN4IX) I seem to only get 8 columns from the 16 available in the csv from the data starting from the second row. Edit: Link updated

Comment: @IBas Assuming your link is the screenshot from the first query, it doesn't make sense to me. I assume the only change you made in the first Query was the file fullpathname. Can you upload a copy of the relevant `csv` file to some sharing site (eg `OneDrive`, `DropBox`, `Drive`) and post a link here?

Comment: Yes, the file path was the only variable I changed. I'm afraid I'm not allowed to give out a copy of the file. I managed to solve the issue by creating two queries for the same file, creating two tables where the first reports the first record in 5 columns (the rest are deleted) and the second takes the rest of the data (16 cols, excl. 1st row). I'm not sure if this is the best approach but it works and I'm open to suggestions. Thanks for the reply. Right now I don't know what causes this issue but If I find out I'll update as soon as possible.

Comment: @IBas perhaps using the actual csv file as a template, you could create a sample file that replicates the problem but is free from sensitive data, changing only the data and not any quotes or separators.

Answer (score 1):

Non-PowerQuery version:

```vb
Sub ReadData()
    
    Const SEP As String = ";"
    Dim content As String, lines As Variant
    Dim arr, headers, ws As Worksheet, n As Long, line, i As Long
    
    content = GetContent("C:\Temp\data.txt")
    lines = Split(content, vbCrLf) 'assuming regular Windows line breaks
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
    
    arr = Split(lines(0), SEP)
    'populate first line
    PutRow ws.Range("A1"), arr
    
    'create the headers
    headers = Array("Col1", "col2", "Col3") 'etc etc
    PutRow ws.Range("A2"), headers
    
    'add the rest of the lines
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    i = 1
    For n = 1 To UBound(lines)
        line = lines(n)
        If Len(line) > 0 Then  '<<<check line has content
            arr = Split(line, SEP)
            PutRow ws.Range("A2").Offset(i), arr
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next n
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub

'return all content from a text file
Function GetContent(f As String) As String
    GetContent = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject"). _
                  OpenTextFile(f, 1).ReadAll()
End Function

'place a zero-based 1D array on a worksheet 
Sub PutRow(c As Range, arr As Variant)
    c.Resize(1, UBound(arr) + 1).Value = arr
End Sub
```

NOTE: use of split to separate the field values only works as long as non of your values contain a semicolon.  If that might be possible I'd look for another approach.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I was wondering would if this approach would be efficient when we have to iterate over 25.000+ rows, or should be the Power Query version be prefered?

Comment: Final clarification is that none of the values have a semicolon within them, although it might be possible that there are empty (null) fields, as shown in the example, it doesn't imply that they will always be empty for all cases.

Comment: You can easily test?  Should be fast enough

Comment: ...I have used it with 100-200k record files and it was fine

Comment: I'm trying but I get an 1004 Application Error when running the program with the complete data set. Currently, I'm trying to find out why this is the case. When debugging the Error, it points me to the PutRow Sub. I didn't know whether to point it out or not because I felt like I was beating around the bush too much. Thanks for the trouble of going through 100k-200k records, my initial question was to get an opinion for it, but you are right, there is no better way to find out than testing, sorry for bothering.

Comment: See edit above - my test file had no blank lines so forgot to account for that